# generic type and assignment problems

Tags: java, oop, generics

I know that , every generic type variable replaced to upper bound that has been determined from the generic definition in the start of method "type-parameter section".

this is from Deitel book

> Actually, all type parameters are replaced with the so-called upper
>   bound of the type parameter, which is specified in the type-parameter
>   section.

according to that , this subcode must be true

```
public  static <E extends Number> void A(  )
 {

E x=  new Double(2.2);

 }
```

but the compiler tell me is compilation error in   **E x=  new Double(2.2);**, although this must be true because the **double is number** .

I know how to process and solve the problem in general by casting , but I ask why this occur ?

Comment: and what error do you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because `E` is a number doesn't mean that it is a `Double`.

Think of it like this, what if E was an Integer.  E is still a Number, but now you are assigning a Double to an Integer.  So the casting behavior is consistent, [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) can be all sorts of different Types, and so could E.

EDIT for Op: The Deitel statement is still correct, If you were assigning the Double to a Number or to an Object then you wouldn't need casting. In this case though, E is not assigning "upwards" it's assigning "laterally" between two possible different Number types.  What if E was a Short, or an Integer, in these cases you wouldnt expect to be able to assign them a Double without casting.

Comment: this means that the quote from deitel book "java how to program" is wrong ?

Comment: Not exactly.  The statement accurately describes how generics are implemented _at runtime_, but not how you should _think_ about generics.

Comment: can you explain it ?? **how generics are implemented at runtime,** ??
to remove the abstraction among my thinks

Comment: I updated the answer, I don't talk about specifically talk about runtime, but all casting happens at that moment.  The gist is, You aren't assigning to a Number, you are assigning to some probable subclass of Number.  This would be like assigning the Double to a Short, or a BigInteger to an Integer.  All of which would need explicit casts.

Comment: the edition not make any scene , of that actual happen at runtime of replaced  to upper bound ... sorry friend but if you can explain

Comment: `Object <- Number <- Double`.  You could assign to any of those without casting.  But E is not exactly Number, assuming E extends Number.  `Object <- Number <- E` so both E and Double inherit from Number. now lets replace E by Integer. `Number <- Integer`.  Would you expect to be able to assign the Double to that Integer without casting(no). Would you expect to be able to assign the Double to that E without casting(no).

Comment: Although you don't explain to me how underlying level at runtime of **  how generics are implemented at runtime** , but you explain good about the case and tired with me .

Comment: I don't think you can **quickly** describe "_how generics work at runtime_".

Answer (score 3):

When you specify `E extends Number`, this means `E` is any subtype of `Number`, or `Number` itself. For example, `E` could be an `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`, etc. This is why your code does not compile - if `E` was `Integer`, for example, it would be wrong to be able to assign a `Double` to the variable of type `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

And yet this works perfectly!

```
public static <E extends Number> void A() {
  E x = (E)new Double(2.2);
}
```

Be nice to your compiler and it will be nice to you. All you need to do is tell it what you mean.

And - of course - since we are actually lying to our compiler now it lets us do scary stuff like:

```
public class Test {
  public static <E extends Number> E makeOne() {
    E x = (E) new Double(2.2);
    return x;
  }

  // Some real compiler abuse.
  public void test() {
    Integer one = Test.<Integer>makeOne();
    Double two = Test.<Double>makeOne();
    Number three = Test.<Double>makeOne();
  }

}
```

To our readers at home ... this is **not** how Generics should be used.

Oh - and by the way, the reason you are seeing your problem is that you are mismatching types without casting.

Your problem is a conceptual one. The type passed in a Generic clause `<E extends Number>` is **not** a place-holder for the type you finally decide to use. You are not just delaying your decision about which type to use. You are making a promise to only use types matching the clause and, if you ever break that promise the compiler must warn you.

The reason your code is not accepted is because you are doing just that, you are breaking that promise. You are saying that although the caller can use **any** `Number` you will use a specific `Number` (`Double`) so you are breaking the rules you have laid down for yourself and the compiler is telling you off.

Answer (score 0):

All you know is that `E` extends `Number`.  Type `E` could be `Integer`, which is also a subclass of `Number`.

Wouldn't make much sense to assign assign `new Double(2.2)` to a variable named `x` of type `Integer`.